# Gparted: Cannot create extended partition

Tags: partition, gparted

I am unable to create an extended partition on my disk in Gparted: the option is greyed out! I resized the primary partition on the disk to leave some unallocated space, and I wanted to make the extended partition there so I could make 3 logical partitions in there, but I can't.

I do not have any other extended partitions on the disk; the only other partition is the primary partition which I do not want to lose data from.

As you can see in this screenshot, the "Extended Partition" option is greyed out and cannot be selected.

[image: Screenshot of the “Create new Partition” dialog]

Any help would be appreciated here!

Output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 114.6 GiB, 123010547712 bytes, 240254976 sectors
Disk model: Ultra Fit       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1       1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/sdb2       1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931.6G 6c unknown
/dev/sdb3                0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/sdb4         27722122   27722568        447 223.5K  0 Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

(By the way, in this state there is only the 1 partition on the disk which is NTFS)

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say there is no partition table, because the "partition" is named `/dev/sdb`. What does it show if you enable "View -> Device Information" in the menu?

Comment: @Freddy - Yeah, device information says `Partition Table: None`.

Comment: @DanielMassey If all data looks okay, you could (1) backup everything. (2) Delete the partition and create a new partition table (menu -> Device -> Create Partition Table), create new partitions and (3) restore your backup.

Comment: You actually have a file-system on your device `/dev/sdb`. You do not even have a partition table and therefore cannot have partitions. @Freddy's comment should be the answer.

Comment: @Freddy - Yep, I've already began the backup and will do it as soon as that is done! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Freddy stated in the comments, it seems there was no partition table at all on this disk. I have resolved this now by creating a partition table on the disk. Thanks for all your help anyway!

Comment: Solved for me the problem! It appears that if you have installed a live-iso to an ssd (or usb), this is done without a partition table. So in case you want to delete this partition , you have to create the partition table again before adding new partitions